# android recycler view with static headers

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am building an android view where I have couple static ui element and then a list view.

```
<LinearLayout>
 <Button/>
 <Text/>
 <Text/>
 <Button/>
 <RecyclerView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

It is guaranteed for me that there are about 5-6 items in the list.

Is there a way for me to create the recycler view such that the whole list will scroll with the whole view?

For example, I wish my view to almost appear as if the 5 or 6 items in the list is made statically, and the whole list scrolls with the header together.

Currently, my list actually goes under the header items. (the two button and two textview)

Comment: Did you try using NestedScrollView as a parent for your whole layout?

Comment: I see. I will try using that. (I didn't know such a view existed lol)

Comment: create a layout on your resources folder and on your activity do something like: ViewGroup myHeader = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_header_layout, yourlistview, false); mylistview.addHeaderView(myHeader, null, false);